# How to check if a list has similar elements with sublists from a multidimensional list

Tags: java, python, arrays, multidimensional-array, contains

I am trying to turn a Python program into a Java program, but I don't know how to convert this section :

```
def X():
for i in range(num):
    for j in range(len(MultidimensionalList)):
        if List[i] not in MultidimensionalList[j]:
            MultidimensionalList[j].append('X')
```

This method put an X in all the sublists of the multidimensional list if they do not have the element List[i].

I saw on the internet that I could use the disjoint method but it is not applicable for the arguments.

So this is what I did with `disjoint()`:

```
public static void X() {
        for(int i=0;i<List.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<MultidimensionalList.length;i++) {
                if(Collections.disjoint(R[i], Gamme[j])) {                      
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming the variable types were defined properly the direct translation of `if List[i] not in MultidimensionalList[j]` would be `if (!MultidimensionalList[j].contains(List[i]))`. By the way: Variables start by naming convention with lowercase letters in Python and Java.

Comment: i get "Cannot invoke contains(String) on the array type String[] :/

Comment: You may use "java.util.ArrayList" instead of arrays then but this will need some more changes.